# Symfony2, HWIOAuthBundle and FOSUserBundle - how to create users

Tags: oauth, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

My goal is to use these bundles to connect to MailChimp OAuth or Facebook (not necessarily as a login option but that could come later - right now just want my app authorized to access the MailChimp API) - I've got the whole process somewhat working in the sense that I can be redirect to MailChimp or Facebook, allow my app and the I am always redirected to to my failur_path as defined in my security.yml. I presume this is correct behavior since I do not have users with the matching tokens. My question is... how do I create these users in the first place? Or rather how do I get the provided oauth token into the user's data for later user/authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's old, but in case someone didn't find it:
https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697